# How to get the X-th position of integer from a string?

Tags: string, numbers, position, element

I have a string that says "12345". 
I want to take the 3rd element from the string to convert it to integer (which in this case, the 3rd element would be '3').
How would I do so ?

I heard that you can use Integer.parseInt(s) but this will return the whole integer of the String. 
I just want one element from it, and at the x-th position.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to simply use String.SubString. Something like:

```
string number = "12345";
string element = number.SubString(2, 1);
```

Where 2 is the position of the third character (remember it's 0 indexed) and 1 is the number of characters to return. You can then turn that into an integer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can do some thing like that...

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(givenString.charAt(xPosition));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The [charAt() method] (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp) should get you what you need

Comment: I tried the string.charAt(x) method, but instead, it returns a character value, and when I convert the char back to Integer, it returns unexpected values =.="